# Run 2 mongodb updates in 1 query based on a field value

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I need to update a record in mongodb where the new value depends on the value of another field in the record.

For instance given the following collection

```
{id: 1, list: []}
{id: 2, list: [6]}
{id: 3, list: []}
{id: 4, list: [6]}
{id: 5, list: []}
```

I want to be able to say:

```
if ('id' is in [1, 3, 5]) => add the value '6' to 'list'
else => remove the value '6' from 'list'
```

The outcome would be:

```
{id: 1, list: [6]}
{id: 2, list: []}
{id: 3, list: [6]}
{id: 4, list: []}
{id: 5, list: [6]}
```

This could be done in 2 update queries, as follows, but I am trying to do it in 1:

```
db.collection.update({$in: [1, 3, 5]}, {$addToSet: {list: 6}})
db.collection.update({$in: [2, 4]}, {$pull: {list: 6}})
```

The code is in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not have a internal case statement as of yet which would allow you to perform this like in SQLs own `case` abilities.

As such you will need to do each separately, however you can change your latter query to be more along the lines of:

```
db.collection.update({$nin: [1, 3, 5]}, {$pull: {list: 6}})
```

That should accomplish the `if` statement you provided better.

Comment: The only reason I had {$in: [2, 4] is that [2, 4] is not necessarily the complement of  [1, 3, 5]. it could be just [2].

Comment: it is always good NOT to use  $nin or any negate operator if possible.

Comment: @RaxitSheth It is fine to use a negation property provided you are not negating a boolean or a low selectivity field which he is not, negation operators can still use a covered index.

Comment: @Sammaye  interesting! Tnx